# What is the highlighted element called and what are the best practices to use this in a product's design?

Tags: usability, terminology, best-practice

Does it have a common terminology? How do you enable a user to use this feature and inform him that he/she can use it. [image: Whats the highlighted element called?]

Comment: Is this some sort of mailshot software? Does the highlighted element represent a value from a database or something the user must add?

Comment: Yea, this is intercom and the highlighted element represents a value from the database. In this scenario, we are bulk mailing a set of customers and the highlighted element will be replaced by the customers name when the mail reaches the customers mailbox.

Answer (score 1):

On a technical level, this is a variable or keyname.

On an interface level, this is an inline button (that I suspect may also be some kind of dropdown / select menu, but I could be wrong).

On a graphic level, this is a pill, or rounded rectangle.  While such elements don't always imply interactivity, shape is one of many common ways to set content apart visually, which is a key element in making interaction discoverable.  The colors and borders also contribute. Here's a concise article on [making click targets discoverable.](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/clickable-elements/)

Comment: On a user level, it might be a placeholder.